# jasper reports, multi select query checkbox type parameter is showing An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator. (5321)

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jasper report 6. here is my jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TestTestMultiQuery" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="90abb488-1239-4b84-865e-291aa3094758">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="mysql_db"/>
    <parameter name="source" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <parameter name="p_source" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[(($P{source}.isEmpty() && $P{source}==null)?"":$P{source}.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "'").replaceAll(", ", "', '"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select id,title,creator_id from need n where ($X{IN,n.source,p_source})]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Long">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="title" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="creator_id" class="java.lang.Long">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

here my *source* param is non-required param. where i ran this report its giving me `An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator. (5321)`
when i make manditory field its working fine for me. what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the () around the IN..

$X{IN does this for you.

I usually do something like

Just so that as I build my SQL I know I have a where clause that works.